# remove specific whitespaces from list items

Tags: python, list, whitespace

I have a huge list of lines, each of which looks as follows

```
1 01 01 some random text
```

The `1 01 01` part is a reference number that changes from line to line. I want to remove the two whitespaces between the three reference numbers, so that the lines look as follows.

```
10101 some random text
```

Obviously, this calls for a `for` loop. The question is what I should write inside the loop I can't use `strip`,

```
for i in my_list:
    i.strip()
```

because that, if anything, would remove all whitespaces, giving me

```
10101somerandomtext
```

which I don't want. But if I write

```
for i in my_list:
    i.remove(4)
    i.remove(1)
```

I get an error message `'str' object has no attribute 'remove'`. What is the proper solution in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If the number is always at the beginning, you can use the fact that [`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) function takes an optional argument `count`:

```
for l in mylist:
    print l.replace(' ', '', 2)
```

Note that I'm doing `print` here for a reason: **you can't change the strings in-place**, because strings are immutable (this is also why they don't have a `remove` method, and `replace` returns a modified string, but leaves the initial string intact). So if you need them in a list, it's cleaner to create another list like this:

```
newlist = [l.replace(' ', '', 2) for l in mylist]
```

It's also safe to overwrite the list like this:

```
mylist = [l.replace(' ', '', 2) for l in mylist]
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly. Instead of creating another list, though, I'm printing the output of `replace` to a .txt file.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `count` argument for [replace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace), to replace the first 2 spaces.

```
a = "1 01 01 some random text"
a.replace(" " , "", 2)
>>> '10101 some random text'
```

Answer (score 1):

[`split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) takes a second argument - the number of splits to make

```
for i in my_list:
    components = i.strip(" ", 3)
    refnum = ''.join(components[:3])
    text = components[3]
```

Or in python 3:

```
for i in my_list:
    *components, text = i.strip(" ", 3)
    refnum = ''.join(components)
```

Comment: think you mean to have `split` in the code instead of `strip`